# Looping through elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, loops

Evening All

I was hoping someone could help me with a jQuery Looping problem I am having.

I have created a sample page here

http://www.csr500.co.uk/websites/v9/preview.html

My issue is regarding the location of the grey bar (bottom left) located on the third item near the bottom with the 'number 3' in it.

I would like the bar to be placed in the bottom left of each item, however when I am looping though the items using a jQuery each function, the bar is pushed down each time because of the various item heights.

I have console.debugged the height of each item and they are incrementing thru correctly but cant quite work out how to place the item and then move onto the next, so that I have three grey stripes, one on each item. Currently I have three grey stripes, all at an identical height of the tallest item.

Any help in sorting out this issue really would be much appreciated.

Thanking you all in advance

Cameron

Comment: Please post the code relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
$(".technologies-used").css("top", margin);
```

Try :

```
$(this).find(".technologies-used").css("top", margin);
```

You see, the looping is not the probleme, but in the loop, you are selecting every element and change its top value.

So all your elements have a `top` of you last item (your last loop).

So using `.find()` will get the element you are searching for inside the element you currently are in your loop.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats probably saved me about an hour of banging my head against a brick wall! Very much appreciated

Comment: If you're going to add code, add it to your answer, not to the question. That's why the change got rejected.

Comment: Perhaps you could ask @user1843002 in a comment to paste it into the question. That way it looks less like a radical edit. They tend to get rejected unless there is a really good reason for it.